# Efficient Script to get all Extended File Properties

Tags: sql, powershell, xp-cmdshell, file-attributes

I'm pretty new working with Powershell and i have some working code but I'm not sure how to get it into an efficient routine to return all of the extended file properties of some video files i have.

I have:

```
# The basic setup for the next steps
$path = 'C:\test\videotocheck.mp4'
$shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application
$folder = Split-Path $path
$file = Split-Path $path -Leaf
$shellfolder = $shell.Namespace($folder)
$shellfile = $shellfolder.ParseName($file)

# This command gets a list of all the extended attributes available for this file
0..500 | Foreach-Object { '{0} = {1}' -f $_, $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($null, $_) }

# These commands get the individual attributes picked out of the list above
$shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, 314)
$shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, 316)
```

All i want to do is provide a filename and have it give me a list back of all of the attributes and their values (if they have one.)

Example:
[image: Example Output]

I intend to use this in a SQL stored procedure. I can work with different types of output if that's easier.

I'm mostly interested in dimensions

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To get all of this extended metadate you could use the function below.
You can give it the path to a single file, or the path to a folder where the files are.

```
function Get-MetaData {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([Psobject[]])]
    Param (
        # Path can be the path to a folder or the full path and filename of a single file
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string]$Path,

        # Pattern is unused if Path is pointing to a single file
        [Alias('Filter')]
        [string]$Pattern = '*.*',

        [Alias('Indices')]
        [int[]]$Properties = 1..500,

        # Recurse is unused if Path is pointing to a single file
        [switch]$Recurse,
        [switch]$IncludeEmptyProperties
    )
    $item = Get-Item -Path $Path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if (!$item) { Write-Error "$Path could not be found."; return }
    if (!$item.PSIsContainer) {
        # it's a file
        $files = @($item)
        $Path  = $item.DirectoryName
    }
    else {
        # it's a folder
        $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter $Pattern -File -Recurse:$Recurse
    }
    $shell  = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
    $objDir = $shell.NameSpace($Path)

    foreach($file in $files) {
        $objFile    = $objDir.ParseName($file.Name)
        $mediaFile  = $objDir.Items()

        foreach($index in $Properties) {
            $name  = $objDir.GetDetailsOf($mediaFile, $index)
            if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($name)) { 
                $value = $objDir.GetDetailsOf($objFile, $index)
                if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($value) -or $IncludeEmptyProperties) {
                    [PsCustomObject]@{
                        Path     = $file.FullName
                        Index    = $index
                        Property = $name
                        Value    = $value
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    # clean-up Com objects
    $null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objFile)
    $null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objDir)
    $null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($shell)
    [System.GC]::Collect()
    [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
}
```

You can of course play around with the different parameters the function can take like `-Pattern '*.mp4'` to only list properties for mp4 files or add switch `-IncludeEmptyProperties` to also list properties that exist for that file type, but have no value for the specified file.

With parameter `Properties` you can give the function an array of int32 values of the property indices to return. If you leave that open, the function tries to get all properties from index 1 to index 500 (if available).

Most of the interesting property indices can be found at:

- audio/video files: `0,1,2,3,4,5,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,26,27,28,36,164,165,194,213,220,223,237,243`
- font files:
  `0,1,2,3,4,5,20,21,25,33,34,164,165,166,196,310`
- image files:
  `0,1,2,3,4,5,9,11,31,164,165,174,175,176,177,178,194,196`

Use it like this:

```
$result = Get-MetaData -Path '<pathToTheFile_OR_pathToTheFolder>'

# output to GridView
$result | Out-GridView

# output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path '<pathToTheOutput.csv>' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Wow! So cool?   I'm pretty new to using these scripts.  Can i call this from a "exec xp_cmdshell "powershell.... " in SQL?  Maybe with Import-Module?

Comment: @jimerb I cannot test this with`xp_cmdshell "powershell.... `, so I guess you just have to try this out yourself. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified version similar to Theo's. It will accept file/folder paths or objects via pipeline or as parameter.

```
Function Get-FileMetaData {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param
    (
        [parameter(valuefrompipeline,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName,Position=1,Mandatory)]
        $InputObject
    )

    begin
    {
        $shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
    }

    process
    {
        foreach($object in $InputObject)
        {
            if($object -is [string])
            {
                try
                {
                    $object = Get-Item $object -ErrorAction Stop
                }
                catch
                {
                    Write-Warning "Error while processing $object : $($_.exception.message)"
                    break
                }
            }

            try
            {
                Test-Path $object -ErrorAction Stop
            }
            catch
            {
                Write-Warning "Error while processing $($object.fullname) : $($_.exception.message)"
                break
            }

            switch ($object)
            {
                {$_ -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]}{
                    write-host Processing folder $object.FullName -ForegroundColor Cyan
                    $currentfolder = $shell.namespace($object.FullName)
                    $items = $currentfolder.items()
                }
                {$_ -is [System.IO.FileInfo]}{
                    write-host Processing file $object.FullName -ForegroundColor Cyan
                    $parent = Split-Path $object
                    $currentfolder = $shell.namespace($parent)
                    $items = $currentfolder.ParseName((Split-Path $object -Leaf))
                }
            }

            try
            {
                foreach($item in $items)
                {
                    0..512 | ForEach-Object -Begin {$ht = [ordered]@{}}{
                        if($value = $currentfolder.GetDetailsOf($item,$_))
                        {
                            if($propname = $currentfolder.GetDetailsOf($null,$_))
                            {
                                $ht.Add($propname,$value)
                            }
                        
                        }    
                    } -End {[PSCustomObject]$ht}
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Write-Warning "Error while processing $($item.fullname) : $($_.exception.message)"
            }
        }
    }

    end
    {
        $shell = $null
    }
}
```

Comment: I've got this working!!  I'm pretty new to using these scripts.  Can i call this from a "exec xp_cmdshell "powershell.... " in SQL?  Maybe with Import-Module?